# String extract when partial string matches-pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Lets consider the following dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'colA':['1234_usa_Name1_xyz','9876_usa_Abc Name2',
                     '123>>usa>>Name3_xyz','123>>abc_usa>>Name4']})
```

And the following list:

`l=['abc name1','abc Name2','Name3',"Name4"]`

---

I am trying to extract the names from the series `colA` when it matches(case insensitive) and returns exactly what is there in the series-->(case must be same as the series has).
I have tried:

```
p=r'({})'.format("|".join([i.title() for i in l]))
#"(Abc Name1|Abc Name2|Name3|Name4)"
df.colA.str.extract(p,expand=False)
```

Which gives me:

```
[NaN, 'Abc Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4']
```

Expected:

```
['Name1','Abc Name2','Name3','Name4']
```

I have also tried with converting both list and series to `lower()` but that doesnt retain the cases in the output.

Could the flags parameter in [`series.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) come to my rescue? Cant seem to get through this.

Appreciate all help I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *partially* means partial words, use `re.findall` with `pd.Series.apply`:

```
import re
p=r'({})'.format("|".join([i.title() for i in l])).replace(' ', '|')
df['colA'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(re.findall(p, x)))
```

Output:

```
0        Name1
1    Abc Name2
2        Name3
3        Name4
Name: colA, dtype: object
```

Comment: Good suggestion :) trying this

Comment: Thanks Chris: ended up using: `df['colA'].str.findall(p).apply(' '.join)` , seemed to love  extract too much. :P

Comment: Lovely! I too sometimes get caught by the extract :) Glad to help!

Comment: Use caution applying this solution generally. This will not always prioritize the extraction of full matches over partial matches. It works for the question input because `'abc name1'` is converted to title case and included in the regex pattern as `'Abc|Name1'` which ensures that it does not match the `'abc'` in `'123>>abc_usa>>Name4'`.

Answer (score 1):

`abc name1` is being compared completely as one string,
 In case of the first element it contains `usa_Name1` which is not starting with abc. so `abc name1` as complete string does not match.

instead what you can do is just split the strings into words and join with `|` (pipe).

`l = map(lambda x: "|".join(x.split(" ")), l)`

Comment: but it does not explain missing `Name4`

Comment: @user7440787 In case of the first element it contains `usa_Name1` which is not starting with abc. so `abc name` as complete string does not match.

Comment: And `name4` was not a `Nan` without any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Not super efficient, but you can prioritize the return of full matches over partial matches while preserving case insensitive matching by breaking the process into a couple of steps. First extract all full matches, then extract all partial matches, and combine the results into a series where partial matches are only used when there is no full match.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':['1234_usa_Name1_xyz', '9876_usa_Abc Name2', '123>>usa>>Name3_xyz', '123>>abc_usa>>Name4']})

l = ['abc name1' , 'abc Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4']

full = df['colA'].str.extract(
    r'({})'.format('|'.join(l)),
    flags=re.I,
    expand=False
    )

partial = df['colA'].str.extract(
    r'({})'.format('|'.join([y for x in l for y in x.split() if y not in l])),
    flags=re.I,
    expand=False
    )

combo = full.combine_first(partial)
print(combo)
# 0        Name1
# 1    Abc Name2
# 2        Name3
# 3        Name4
```